# Exchange id in camel request ends with even number

Tags: apache-camel

I am using Apache Camel in  OSGI scenario using Karaf in version 2.15.1. I am using the exchange.getExchangeId() to print the exchange id in a request/reply. The exchange pattern is set to InOnly. The route looks like this:

```
<route id="ip_client_rpc">
    <from uri="restlet:http://localhost:7070/lsp/patron/id?restletMethod=POST&amp;synchronous=true"/>
     <to uri="log:${headers}"/>
    <setExchangePattern pattern="InOnly"/>
    <process ref="rabbit_client"/>
    <to uri="log:${headers}"/>
  </route>
```

However when I print the exchange id sent to the rabbitmq queue it always ends with an even number.

```
Request from client:ID-VirtualDev-49301-1443430754519-5-6
Request from client:ID-VirtualDev-49301-1443430754519-5-8
Request from client:ID-VirtualDev-49301-1443430754519-5-10
Request from client:ID-VirtualDev-49301-1443430754519-5-12
Request from client:ID-VirtualDev-49301-1443430754519-5-14
```

Is there a reason why the final digit is always even? Is there another exchange being created that I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Camel uses the same id generator for generating unique ids for different things, its just by chance that its even in this case. Could be that a breadcrumb or message id was also generated that takes the odd number.